# Initializing a SessionManager in Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Just upgraded to Alamofire 4.0. Having issues with the session manager. Firstly actually initialising it:

Previously:

```
let alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Now:

```
let alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: SessionDelegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager?)
```

What is the session delegate object for and why does it have to be included now? What is the trust policy?

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/4.0.0/#session-delegate Look at the part talking about Session Delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
var alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```